# Azure AD VPN Conditional Access with StrongSwan

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, vpn, intune

Can we integrate Azure AD VPN Conditional Access with StrongSwan VPN server?
I have gone through the following articles and I know that a similar setup can be done Windows Remote Access VPN and Azure AD Conditional Access

1. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/microscott/build-your-own-windows-10-vpn-lab-and-configure-it-with-intune/
2. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/microscott/add-conditional-access-to-your-windows-10-vpn-with-intune-and-azure-ad/